# Are these parasite sites and could they be impacting my site's stats?

Tags: seo, google

My site stats have been dropping considerably in recent months as you can see here:

[image: Site Stats Screenshot]

My site still appears number 1 on google for "username generator" but - if I search for my site via this search string on google:

`username generator jimpix -jimpix.co.uk`

([link to search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=username%20generator%20jimpix%20-jimpix.co.uk&rlz=1C1JJTC_en-GBGB1053GB1053&oq=username%20generator%20jimpix%20-jimpix.co.uk&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i64j69i65.11008j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#ip=1)), then many sites appear in the search results which show the same title and short description in the search results as my site, but which direct the user to dodgy websites - though all pretty much seem to redirect to the same few websites.

Example URLs:

- `https://vmfdjzkbt.bwslam19.de`
- `https://e73m8yfs.cieszczykfotografia.pl`
- `https://vdwnrlptq.cieszczykfotografia.pl`
- `https://6trwr7h.lavka-lakomstv.ru`
- `https://tnfxmpslq.drogotex.pl`

Could this issue be having a negative impact on my site, and, is there anything I can do about it?

What is the term for this type of issue - is it a parasite website or something else?

Any advice much appreciated.